# Reusing OAuth Access Tokens

Tags: php, oauth, access-token

On my site, I intend to offer users the ability to authenticate via OAuth.  I don’t want to ask them to first register with me and then connect an external account; I want to offer single sign on.

I believe we’re supposed to reuse Access Tokens; certainly within sessions and even between them.

Google goes so far as to say they’ll limit the number of access tokens to [10 per user per application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth#prepToken).  (Apparently Google still supports OAuth1, but recommends Auth2 now)  10 is a pretty small number.

Using cookies ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820815/what-to-do-with-twitter-oauth-token-once-retreived)) seems like a good plan for identifying a user between sessions, but I’m having trouble with the scenario where a user has deleted cookies or connects from a new machine.

How do I know who the user is before I’ve requested another Access Token for them?  Request tokens do not contain the userid, right?

Thanks

Comment: First, I think you should check out the difference between Oauth and OpenId (A single signon authentication) http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/07/14/openid-oauth-difference/en/ When you say users? do you mean users on your application or third party applications trying to access user data stored on your server?

Comment: I agree, OpenID would be a better fit but Twitter is my #1 target... so OAuth it must be. "single sign on" was bad phrasing on my part.  By "users" I mean my app's users; the Resource Owner in the OAuth trinity.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to maintain your own user accounts anyway, no matter which protocol and which provider you choose. A token (or a URL in the case of OpenID) that you get from a provider is unique for a given user and you are supposed to associate it with your internal user account and recognize user by it.

If you don't want to provide any registration UI it's okay: just get the token, retrieve all the user info you need from the provider and store all this somewhere in your database. You will also have to issue and recognize your own cookie for your users, or else they'll be forced to go through provider auth every time they visit your site.

Comment: I completely agree, that's what I intend to do.  I guess I should have explained it as "users won't have a password for my site".  My question applies directly to my stored user information... if they log in from another machine, I just don't see a way around the generation of a new access token before I can match them to my stored registration.

Comment: Yes, if it's another machine and you don't have an existing user cookie then the only way is to ask for a new token. However it doesn't mean you will end up with a new account: most providers yield the same token for the same user (for your client_id) and if not, you can get a persistent user id from the provider specific API (like the Twitter handle from Twitter).